# Need help with reducing cost of view's group by

Tags: sql-server, view, group-by

I have a view which joins couple tables and returns a list of available book copies. My view creation code is as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW AvailableCopies AS
SELECT Product.title, CONCAT(Author.firstName, ' ', Author.lastName) as Author_name, ProductType.pType as Product_type, Product.lendable, count(BookCopy.bisbn) as Copy_count
FROM Product
INNER JOIN BookCopy on BookCopy.bisbn = Product.isbn
INNER JOIN Author on Product.authorId = Author.id
LEFT JOIN ProductType on ProductType.id = Product.typeId
WHERE BookCopy.Available = 'true'
GROUP BY Product.title, Author.firstName, Author.lastName, Product.lendable, ProductType.pType;
```

The problem that I cannot get rid of, is `GROUP BY` line. I cannot omit it, if I do, I get the following error:

> ```
> Error: Column 'Product.title' is invalid in the select list 
> because it is not contained in either an aggregate function 
> or the GROUP BY clause.
> ```

I spent quite a lot of time online, trying to solve this issue in some cheaper way than adding all my selected columns into `GROUP BY`, but sadly no luck. Execution plan says that my group by statement costs 40-41% of whole process! Is there a way to solve this? This view returns 37,5K results, at the moment for education purposes, I am only returning `TOP 20` in my nodeJs application, but it is really frustrating to wait 8-10 seconds for a simple page to load, with a size of 20 in a recordset. I am aware of caching, but I would like to keep this solution as a last option for now.

pastetheplan is not accepting my execution plan xml so I cannot provide it.

After view creation I call `Select TOP 20 from AvailableCopies` . My database is hosted on Azure, I was trying to find version, but I couldn't. But as it is Azure, I assume SQL server 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your indexes, but something worth trying is to grab the copy count in a subquery or CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT Product.title, CONCAT(Author.firstName, ' ', Author.lastName) as Author_name, ProductType.pType as Product_type, Product.lendable, BC.Copy_count
FROM Product
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM BookCopy 
  WHERE BookCopy.bisbn = Product.isbn
  AND BookCopy.Available = 'true'
  ) AS BC(Copy_count)
INNER JOIN Author on Product.authorId = Author.id
LEFT JOIN ProductType on ProductType.id = Product.typeId
WHERE BC.Copy_count>0;
```

Comment: Wow this increased response time significantly. Thanks for the help, I will investigate query you provided and will try to understand it.